# Does the assignment sending every topological space to its sheaf hom functor a functor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, functors

Let $X$ be a topological space. Given sheaves $F,G\in\text{Sh}(X)$, the sheaf hom of $F$ and $G$ is the sheaf $\text{Hom}_X(F,G)$ of $X$ defined on objects by
$$\text{Hom}_X(F,G)(U)=\text{Nat}(F|_U,G|_U)$$
(where $F|_U$ is the restriction of $F$ to $U$). This in turn defines a functor
$$\text{Hom}_X:\text{Sh}(X)^\mathrm{op}\times \text{Sh}(X)\to \text{Sh}(X)$$
What I want to know is whether if the assignment $X\mapsto \text{Hom}_X$ defines yet another functor
$$\mathbf{Top}\to [\text{Sh}(-)^\mathrm{op}\times \text{Sh}(-), \text{Sh}(-)]$$
(I don't think the rightmost notation is formal enough but should be evident on what I'm trying to say).

Comment: In order to define a functor, you need to specify what happens on morphisms and then check that what you've specified preserves identities and compositions. So, what does your proposed functor do to morphisms?

Comment: Say you have a continuous function $f:X\to Y$. How do you obtain a functor  $[\text{Sh}(X)^{\text{op}}\times\text{Sh}(X),\text{Sh}(X)]\to[\text{Sh}(Y)^{\text{op}}\times\text{Sh}(Y),\text{Sh}(Y)]$?

Comment: I do not think it's evident what you're trying to say, actually, because there's no obvious way to interpret your proposed codomain as a category. It would have to be some category in which $Hom_X$ is simultaneously an object for every $X$, in which case the codomain should be a category of functors, but there are many of those, and it's not even clear that's what you're thinking of.

Comment: @KevinArlin
I think the only sensible interpretation of the codomain in the question is the coproduct of categories
$$\coprod_{X\in\mathrm{Top}}[\mathrm{Sh}(X)^{\mathrm{op}}\times\mathrm{Sh}(X),\mathrm{Sh}(X)]$$
if that makes sense at all (I worry about size issues, but I think you can arrange so that this thing is well defined).

Comment: Huh, "the only sensible interpretation" may be an overstatement. But it is one possible interpretation and in this case it's we cannot have a functor, since we don't have where to send the continuous functions. It may be better to consider the same objects but with functors between homs over different categories. Anyway, your point about there not being an obvious way to interpret the codomain stays strong.